# Get data from SQLite database to intent through "onItemClick" on item in ListView Android

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, android-intent, onitemclick

I really need your help.

I have a database with latitude and longitude data, here the example:

id_***_*__*_****name****_*____***lat****_*__*_*____**_long

1_***_*___***hotel one****_*__***6.1234****_*__*_*__**-106.12345

2_***_*__***hotel two****_*___***6.54321****_*__*_*_**-107.23456

3_***_*_***hotel three****_*__***7.12345****_*__*_*_**-106.98765

The data display in ListView on Android. And i use onItemClick, so if i click one of the item in ListView it will go to

`Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr="+lat_var+","+long_var))`

But the problem is if i click one of the item in ListView the data in lat_var and long_var on intent above won't give me the lat and long data from my database...

Here my code, can you edit it, so if i click one of the item in ListView it will give me the lat and long data from my database. For example if i click hotel two the lat_var will change to 6.54321 and the long_var will change to -107.23456 on that intent.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase dbs = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String get_lat = "SELECT lat FROM hoteltbl";
            Cursor result_lat = dbs.rawQuery(get_lat, null);
            double lat_var = result_lat.getColumnIndex("lat");
            String get_long = "SELECT lat FROM hoteltbl";
            Cursor result_long = dbs.rawQuery(get_long, null);
            double long_var = result_long.getColumnIndex("long");

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr="+lat_var+","+long_var));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

I don't know if the problem is my syntax or what. Please fix my code. I really thanks for anyone who answer this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, only one query is necessary. No need to query your table twice.
Second, you need to adapt your query with parameters from your selection:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {id) {    
    String selectedItem = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + selectedItem + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase dbs = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = dbs.rawQuery(query, null);
    result.moveToFirst();

    double lat = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("lat"));
    double long = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("long"));

    ....
```

This code was written in the StackOverflow editor, it might not work as such, but will give you an idea.

(Also, don't add suffixes "_var", or "_long" to your variables, it's not necessary in a strongly-typed language like Java)

Comment: Thx for the answer, i just use it. But how to use getListAdapter() method. In my case can u provide the code?