# Have complication with getListAdapter Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

I want to get latitude and longitude data from sqlite database.

So i use this code below, but there is a problem in `getListAdapter()`. It say that i must create '`getListAdapter()`' method. I'm searching on the net, but there is no example for `getListAdapter()` method.

Can you fix my code. So if i click the item it will give me the lat and long data from my database.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
String selectedItem = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + selectedItem + "'";
SQLiteDatabase dbs = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor result = dbs.rawQuery(query, null);
result.moveToFirst();

double lat = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("lat"));
double longi = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("long"));

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr="+lat+","+longi));
startActivity(intent);

}
```

By the way, this is the problem from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8285453/1049501)

Comment: In `ListActivity`, you can simply use `getListAdapter()`;
In `ListView`, you can use `your_listview_name.getAdapter()`

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to extend ListActivity. You simply need to find the listview and call its getAdapter() method.

Here is your updated code.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.YOURLISTVIEW);
String selectedItem = (String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
String query = "SELECT lat, long FROM hoteltbl WHERE name = '" + selectedItem + "'";
SQLiteDatabase dbs = dbHotelHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor result = dbs.rawQuery(query, null);
result.moveToFirst();

double lat = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("lat"));
double longi = result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex("long"));

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=&daddr="+lat+","+longi));
startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extends ListActivity to have getListAdapter method.
Take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial.

If you want to get item, you should use getItem(position) method from adapter which was set to ListView