# set- and getListAdapter error

Tags: java, android, sql, adapter

I don't know why it shows an error. Can somebody help me.

```
public class MainActivityT extends Activity {
    private VerlaufDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_t);


        datasource = new VerlaufDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Entry> values = datasource.getAllEntries();


        ArrayAdapter<Entry> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Entry>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

In the next Line it shows me an error, namely:

```
Multiple marlcers at this line
- The method setArrayAdapter(ArrayAdapter< Entry>) is undefined for the type MainActivityT
-Uno broakpoint:MainActivityT [lino: 3S] - onCroato(Bundlo)
- The method setlistAdapter(ArrayAdapter< Entrv>) is undefinod for tho type MainActivitvT

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }




    List<Entry> AufgabenListe = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    public void VerlaufKlick(View view)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

In the next Line it shows me an error, namely:
Multiple makers at this line
- The method getArrayAdapter() is undefined for the type MainActivityT
- The method qetlistAdapter() is undefined for the tvpe MainActivitvT

```
        ArrayAdapter<Entry> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Entry>) getListAdapter();
        Entry comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.button1:
          String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
          int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
          comment = datasource.createEntry(comments[nextInt]);
          adapter.add(comment);
          break;

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    @Override
      protected void onResume() 
      {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() 
      {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
      }


}
```

Comment: Have you checked this yet? [have-complication-with-getlistadapter-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286350/have-complication-with-getlistadapter-android)

Comment: i don't understand what you don't understand in the error description. it says your class doesn't have the methods you try to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity need to extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`.

There is no method setListAdapter/getListAdapter available in `Activity` class. They are available if you extend `ListActivity`.

Read this [post](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) on how to use ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListActivity instead of Activity as base class